# How to view tasks count history after nightly autoscale in AWS ECS service

Tags: amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, autoscaling

I have set autoscale for an ECS service (fargate). It has run over night and now I wish to see a graph or any other history of the tasks count. Can't find this in ECS nor in cloudwatch. Any idea how?

Comment: Not sure with fargate, but I think if you do SampleCount of the services CPUUtilization it should be 1 per task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [CloudWatch Container Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html) that will provide you with a view of task counts for your service (along many other metrics). See picture.

This has an additional cost though. It could be possible to build something ad-hoc to track the tasks that does not involve using Container Insights. For example, [this is a small toy project](https://github.com/mreferre/fargatecount) I built to track ALL fargate tasks/pods running in a single account/region. You could possibly adapt it to only track a specific ECS service.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, actually my mistake was that I didn't enabled container insights as you suggested. Had to create the cluster again.